# Is there any way to selected drop down option and submit form in a website and get the received file in google sheets using google api?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am setting a automatic google sheets to generate a report. Where I need to fetch a tsv file from a website http://resi4web1.bytedialer.org:888/vicidial/rpi_lead_report_export.php
 by selecting some fields from drop down lists and submitting. I want to automatically import the received tsv file to google sheets. Any idea to get along this?

I am trying with below code to log the content in logger console first.

```
function importtSVFromWeb() 
{ 

  var formdata= 
  {
     'campaign:':"---ALL---",
     'Inbound Groups:':"59_GAFOPINBOUND",
     'Lists:':"---ALL---",
     'Statuses:':"CCPLED",
     'User Groups:':"---ALL---",
   }
  var options =
   { "method" : "get",
     "headers" : { 
     "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode('Data1' + ":" + 
      '2r7iM1')},
     "Payload":formdata , 
     "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
  var tsvurl="http://resi4web1.bytedialer.org:888/vicidial/rpi_lead_report_export.php?"  ;

  var tsvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tsvurl,options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(tsvContent);
}
```

I expect to receive a tsv file content in logger console. but I am getting HTML contents.

Comment: On executing the above function I am getting the following in logs.
[19-04-23 15:56:14:257 PDT] <HTML><HEAD>
<script language="JavaScript" src="calendar_db.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>ADMINISTRATION: RPI Export Leads Report</title>
<script language="Javascript">
var field_name = '';
var user = 'Data1';
var epoch = '1556060174';
 var weak = new Image();
 weak.src = "images/weak.png";
 var medium = new Image();

Comment: Kindly include all debug data in your question by [edit]ing it. Read [mcve] and [ask].  You seem to be getting html directly. Is this a api?  if so, does it have any documentation?Clarify all such questions in your question by editing it.

Comment: From your script, you use the GET method for requesting. In this case, the value of ``payload`` is used as the query parameter. But in your URL, the last character of ``http://resi4web1.bytedialer.org:888/vicidial/rpi_lead_report_export.php?`` is ``?``. ``?`` is duplicated. So how about removing the last character ``?`` from the URL and trying it again? But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. Because if the method for requesting is not correct, other error occurs. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: If I try with a Post request how can I request the text file. Which is received by selecting some list fields and clicking submit button.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone copied one of the standard Vicidial reports for you to generate custom output. While most of the reports in Vicidial generate a downloadable CSV file, all require that the options for the report (including credentials) are included in the GET or POST to generate the CSV. If you're not sure what I mean, try grabbing one of the "download" links from a generic report.

Your problem with this report appears to be that the output is merely html and not the downloadable file which you seek.

```
CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

TSV files should have

```
CONTENT="text/tab-separated-values; charset=utf-8"
```

As such, until you've gotten the output from the custom report to provide a TSV, you obviously can not import a TSV that isn't there. First try on one of the standard CSV download links to see the difference. Then modify the report in question to provide TSV instead of HTML or CSV, then you can work out importing.